# Can books be arranged into bags?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms

I'm trying to find an algorithm (sub exponential) to answer the following question (informal): given a (finite) set of distinct books of different (positive integer) sizes and a (finite) set of bags of different (positive integer) sizes, **such that each book is allowed to enter only some of the bags**, can all the books be arranged into the bags? (the actual solution is not important, rather its existence).

Or a little more formal: Let $G$ be a bipartite graph with vertex parts $P_1$ (books) and $P_2$ (bags) (all edges are between $P_1$ and $P_2$). Let $w$ be a positive integer weight function on the edges (books size) such that if $e_1$ and $e_2$ are incident with the same vertex in $P_1$ then $w(e_1)=w(e_2)$, and let $c$ be a positive integer function on the vertices of $P_2$ (bag capacity).

Define the function $f_G(v)$ for every vertex $v$ in $G$ to be the sum of weights of the edges incident with it; $\displaystyle f_G(v) = \sum_{e=(v',v)}w(e)$.

I'm looking for an algorithm to answer the question: does $G$ have a subgraph $H$ in which the degree of every vertex in $P_1$ is $1$ and for every vertex $v$ in $P_2$ we have $f_H(v)\leq c(v)$?

Thank you!

Comment: Is this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem (or even harder than this?)

Comment: Reading the problem it would seem to allow that there is only one, i.e. the same, bag that each book may enter, in which case the answer is no (unless that bag can hold multiple (all) books). Perhaps the question needs clarification ?

Comment: Hi @TomCollinge, could you be more specific what should I clarify? Did you mean about the mapping from books to legal bags? Each book is allowed into a (non-empty) subset of the bags. Each book has a size and each bag has a capacity.

Comment: If each book is allowed into a non-empty subset of the bags, can it be the same subset in each case (i.e. for every book) and can the subset consist of just one bag ?

Comment: Sure, and in this case you merely need the bag to fit all the books.

Comment: Seems then that trivially all the books can be put in bags: every book fits into at least one bag and the bags can hold any number of books ?

Comment: no, the bags have a finite capacity and in many scenarios there is no solution.

Comment: Hi @Irvan, thank for the direction, this is a rather general case of a packing problem. But I couldn't find a variation of a packing algorithm in which each element has its own map to a subset of bins (rather than minimizing the number of bins).

Comment: Since the bin packing problem is NP-hard, and can be reduced to your problem, this problem is NP-hard as well. For the existence of a sub exponential algorithm for NP-hard problems, the general answer is there is no known algorithm. See http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9813/are-there-subexponential-time-algorithms-for-np-complete-problems

Comment: Thanks @Irvan, added an answer based on your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an answer following @Irvan's comment above:

The bin packing problem ("Given $n$ items of sizes $d_1,...d_n$ and $m$ bins with capacity $c_1,...,c_m$ store all the items using the smallest number of bins.") could be reduced to this problem in polynomial time.

If we had the algorithms in the question, we could map the items to books and bins to bags, allowing each book to enter **every** bag. And the question of smallest number of bins is answered by running the algorithm a maximum of $m$ times (sorting the bins in decreasing order and adding a bin at every run).

Thus, the problem in question is NP-hard.